# Terraform destroy failed - state file not updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I deployed AWS infrastructure using Terraform and the state file is maintained in S3. Now  I wanted to destroy this infrastructure and hence running a build which runs `terraform plan` followed by `terraform destroy`

This destroyed most of the resources but got stuck while destroying one s3 bucket, so i manually killed the step. I noticed that the state file in s3 was unaltered. Now when I re-run the build which has `terraform plan` followed by `terraform destroy`, the plan step fails because the actual infrastructure does not match the one in the state file.

I would like to know how to rectify this.

Is there a way I can update the state file manually to reflect the current infrastructure?

Comment: You can manually remove resources from state file if it has non-existing resources: [teraform state rm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html).

Comment: @Marcin There are quite a lot of resources. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not sure. You can wait a bit, maybe someone will provide full answer.

Comment: Does the normal `terraform state rm` not fix this for you?

Answer (score 4):

As a "wrapper" to @Marcin's proposed solution above you could use `terraform state rm` within a basic bash loop based on the output of `terraform state list`. Below a simple example:

List resources in state file

```
$ terraform state list
data.aws_ami.amazon_linux
data.aws_subnet_ids.def_vpc_public_subnets
data.aws_vpc.def_vpc
aws_instance.test1
aws_security_group.sec_ssh_ping
```

(send list to a text file)

```
$ terraform state list > state_list.txt
```

(Edit state_list.txt so that it contains only resources you want deleted)
(backup state file)

Delete Resources listed in file with a bash loop

```
$ for s in $(cat state_list.txt) ;do  echo "removing $s"; terraform state rm $s ; done
removing data.aws_ami.amazon_linux
Removed data.aws_ami.amazon_linux
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
removing data.aws_subnet_ids.def_vpc_public_subnets
Removed data.aws_subnet_ids.def_vpc_public_subnets
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
removing data.aws_vpc.def_vpc
Removed data.aws_vpc.def_vpc
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
removing aws_instance.test1
Removed aws_instance.test1
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
removing aws_security_group.sec_ssh_ping
Removed aws_security_group.sec_ssh_ping
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
```

I would be extra careful and try this in a test account/environment before hitting any important/production infrastructure.